# A problem in locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Let $X$ be locally compact Hausdorff and $Y$ be Hausdorff.

(a) If $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and open map then show that $f(X)$ is locally compact.

(b) If $f: X \to Y$ is onto continuous and open map then show that for any compact subset $K$ of $Y$ there is a compact subset $C$ of $X$ such that $f(C)=K$.

I have solved (a), for (b) I thought I could solve it straightforwardly by using the fact that $f(f^{-1}(K))=K$ since $f$ is onto and show that $C=f^{-1}(K)$ is compact in $X$ but as shown in the below picture I have confronted a problem. So I've thought about using the result in (a) but my efforts have been unsuccessful so far. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: $f^{-1}(K)$ is in general not compact. But if you start with a covering $\{ U_\alpha : \alpha \in A\}$ of $f^{-1}(K)$ such that $\overline{U_\alpha}$ is compact for all $\alpha$, what do you get?

Comment: Hmm... I don't really see anything yet can you explain a bit more?

Comment: How can I come up with such a covering in the first place?

Comment: $X$ is locally compact, so for every $x\in C$, let $U_x$ be a relatively compact open neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Okay I see how I can come up with such a covering but I still don't see where you intend to take me can you help me out?

Comment: Look again at your notes. And don't forget that what you want is a compact *subset* $M\subset C$ such that $f(M) = K$. [Yes, the naming is unfortunate, but I guess you can deal with that.]

Comment: Thanks a lot but is there any particular motive behind such reasoning? I'd like to know how you thought of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x\in f^{-1}(K)$, consider an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$, with compact closure. Then $f(U_x)$ is open and the family $\{f(U_x):x\in f^{-1}(K)\}$ is an open cover of $K$. Then
$$
K\subseteq f(U_{x_1})\cup f(U_{x_2})\cup\dots\cup f(U_{x_n})
$$
for some $x_1,\dots,x_n\in f^{-1}(K)$. Take
$$
C=(\overline{U_{x_1}}\cup \overline{U_{x_2}}\cup\dots\cup\overline{U_{x_n}})\cap f^{-1}(K)
$$

> Then $C$ is compact and $f(C)\subseteq f(f^{-1}(K))=K$. If $y\in K$, then $y=f(x)$ with $x\in U_{x_i}$ for some $i$, $1\le i\le n$. So…